# Set the Property value to an ini file WIX

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

I was setting a property value inside a Dialog using  Edit Control. But when i used the same property for writing inside an ini value it is not writing the updated value and writing only old value. My WIX source code is given below(writing only important codes  as my wix code is too large)

```
<Property Id="testNumber" Value="1122" />
<CustomAction Id="SettestNumber" Property="ModifiedtestNumber" Value="[testNumber]" />

<ComponentGroup Id="INIFileGroup">
  <Component Id="IniFile" Guid="{0ded271b-9268-49e7-8c13-60c7538acc25}" KeyPath="yes" Directory="DirCfg" >
    <IniFile Id="IniPath" Action="addLine" Directory="Dirtest" Key="testkey" Name="test.ini" Section="test" Value="[ModifiedtestNumber]" />
  </Component>
</ComponentGroup>

<InstallUISequence>
 <Custom Action="SettestNumber" Sequence="1299"/>
</InstallUISequence>

            <Dialog Id="testNumberUI" X="50" Y="50" Width="375" Height="270" Title="[ProductName]" CustomPalette="yes">
            <Control Type="Edit" Id="test_Number" Width="50" Height="15" X="258" Y="53" Property="testNumber" Text="{50}" TabSkip="yes"/>
        </Dialog>
```

I am giving the value 1212 in the Control edit box and installing but inside the test.ini file it is not getting updated and value is 1122. Could someone please provide a way for me to update the Modifedtestnumber to the ini file

Note:
When i put the Custom action inside < InstallExecuteSequence/> the value inside the ini file was null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your property need to be public (all caps TESTNUMBER) and marked with Secure attribute so that it's listed in the SecureCustomPublicProperties property.  Also be aware that properties are not persisted.  You need to use something like the WiX remember property pattern for the value to be loaded from the INI file during subsequent transactions such as repairs and upgrades.

Comment: Here's a link to the mentioned remember me pattern http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/5/2/the-wix-toolsets-remember-property-pattern/